# How to assign tableview cell count value to programmatic UILabel?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have created a UILabel programmatically and would like for it to display the number of cell in a TableView.

I have the following code in my `viewDidLoad()`

```
let lb = UILabel()
lb.textAlignment = .center
lb.numberOfLines = 0
lb.text = "Num of Cells: \(structure.count)"
lb.font = UIFont.boldSystemFont(ofSize: 18.0)

newView.addSubview(lb)
```

And would like to assign the following `structure.count` value to it.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return structure.count
}
```

Just doing the following in `viewDidLoad()` produces a `0` as it loads before the tableview cells load:

```
lb.text = "Num of Cells: \(structure.count)"
```

How can I assign the structure.count value to the label once the cells all load in the tableview?

**Structure is being populated like this:**

```
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: request) { data, _, error in
        guard let data = data else { return }


        do {
            self.structure = try JSONDecoder().decode([StructOne].self,from:data)
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
        catch {
            print(error)
        }

        }.resume()

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are loading your data asynchronously, you can't update the label in `viewDidLoad`. You need to update the label once `structure` has been populated.

Simply move:

```
lb.text = "Num of Cells: \(structure.count)"
```

to be inside the `DispatchQueue.main.async` block along with the call to reload the table view.

Comment: How should l define the programmatic UILabel so that it is available in that in function?

Comment: Make it a property instance of a local variable.